Found an interesting cogsci/neurosci question in some other SE branch? Link it here
There are other stack exchange websites which also contain cognitive science and neuroscience questions. This includes the Biology stack exchange, philosophy stack exchange, and some other sites. Particularly in BioSe there are lot of "treasure". 
I think it would be very useful if these questions are grouped or classified  and linked with Cogsci/ (now psychology and neuroscience). It will help add a more logical structure and accessibility to SE sites. 
Regards

What are you proposing exactly?  Such questions are already linked on the psych.SE chat room, The Axon Terminal.

that is difficult to browse

I upvote for the idea about bringing every related question together, not about putting them in meta

I think we should have a SE-wise related question list whenever a question is being typed in one site
.
.
.
But hey, why not help them google the question as well?

Some relevant tags in BioSE: 
Action potential, Alcohol, Altruism, artificial-neural-network, Autonomic-nervous-system, behaviour, bioacoustics, biofeedback, biological-networks , blood-brain-barrier, brain, brain-stem, cell-membrane, cell-signaling, central-nervous-system, chemical-communications, chronobiology, circadian -rhythm, cocaine, cognition, color, communication, computational-model, cranial nerves, dendrites, dendritic spines, dopamine, dreaming, dynorphin, echolocation, eeg, electrical-stimulation, electroencephalography, electromuscular, electrophysiology, endocrinology, epigenetiics, eusociality, event-related-potential, eyes, gender, gustation, hallucinogens, hearing, histamine, homosexuality, human ear, human eye, hypothalamus, information, information-theory, instinct, intelligence, intracellular-transport, iris, language, learning, life, light, Linguistics, Lipids, melatonin, membrane, membrane-transport, memory, movement, mri, muscles, network, neural-engineering, neuroanatomy, neurodegenerative-disorders, neurogenesis,  neuromodulation, neuron, neurophysiology, neuroplasticity, neuroscience, neurotransmitter, nose, odour, olfaction, opioid, optics, osmoregulation, osmosis, perception, peripheral-nervous-system, photoperiod, prion, psychiatry, psychology, psychoneuropharmacology, psychophysics, receptor, reflexes, schizophrenia, sensation, senses, sexual-selection, signaling, signal-processing, sleep, smoking, sociality, sociobiology, synesthecia, systems-biology, temperature, thermoregulation, touch, ultrasound, vision, visualization, visual-system, vocal-communication, 
................
Some relevant tags in Medical Science SE : 
adolescents-teenagers , adrenaline, alcoholic-alcoholism, alcohol-withdrawal, alertness-level, amphetamine, anaesthesia, analgesic-pain-killer, angular-spatial-resoluton, anti-anxiety-meds, antidepressants, anti-nausea, antipsychotic, aspergers-syndrome, artificial-flavor, astigmatism, audiology, auditory-cortex, autism, b-12-supplements, behavior, benzodiazepines, bipolar-disorder, beta-blockers, blind, brain, brain-damage, brain-exercises, brain-fog, breaking-habits, caffeine, calm-soothing-strategies, cannabidiol, cannabinoids, cannabis, carbonated-carbonation, carpal-tunnel-syndrome, circadian-rythym, cluster-headache, cns-central-nervous-systm, coffee, cognitive-science, communication, concentration, concussion, corticosteroids, cortisol, csf-cerebrospinal-fluid, ct-scans, deaf, decibels, delusions, dementia, depression, depth-perception, dermatillomania,development-disorder developmental-milestones, dha-docosahexaenoic-acid, dizziness, dopamine, double-vision, downs-syndrome, drowning, drowsy, drug-tapering-weaning, drug-withdrawal, dyslexia-dyslexic, ejaculation , elderly-seniors-aged-old, emotional-abuse ,  emotional-eating , endocrinology, endorphins, epa-eicosapentaenoic-acid, epilepsy, epinephrine, erection estrogen, ethanol, eye, eye-strain,  fatigue, fatty-acids, feinting, field-of-vision-fov-test, fight-or-flight, food-addiction, forgetfulness, gait-walk-abnormalities, ganglion-cysts, goosebumps, hangover-hungover, 
Some selected interesting questions: 
(an edit is going on)

Meta is not the place for 'main content'.
In case an answer from another site is relevant here:

be sure to paste a link to it in the comments on the question on this site.

In case a question is relevant here:

you can share it in chat.
you can mention in comments that such questions are also welcome on our site. Especially in case it does not attract any answers.

However, the person asking the question decided to post the question on the other site and in the end it is up to them to choose where to post it. It happens frequently a question can be on topic on multiple sites. Stack Exchange does not allow cross-posting. As long as the question is asked somewhere, it is fine. Creating links between them you can always do in comments/question body/answer body.
